# Install mod_jk with Apache 2.2

Tags: tomcat6

I have downloaded mod_jk-1.2.28-httpd-2.2.X.so for Apache 2.2 running on CentOS, and set up as per http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html. When I try to start httpd it fails with the following error:
"Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 993 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/conf/jk/mod_jk.conf-auto: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk-1.2.28-httpd-2.2.X.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk-1.2.28-httpd-2.2.X.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32"

Does that mean that mod_jk-1.2.28-httpd-2.2.X.so has not been properly compiled?. What can I do about that?
Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have a 32-bit module, but are not running a 32-bit httpd. Install the proper gcc package from the repositories and rebuild the module.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, I installed the Tomcat Connector using yum:

```
yum search mod_jk

mod_jk-ap20.x86_64 : Tomcat mod_jk connector for Apache 2.0.x

mod_jk-ap22.x86_64 : Tomcat mod_jk connector for Apache 2.x

yum install mod_jk
```